# Unaccompanied minor flying from the USA to Russia

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, russia

My daughter, 15, may need to fly to Moscow, Russia from California, unaccompanied. What paperwork will she need to do this? Will she be allowed to? She speaks fluent Russian and English so that she will have no problem with communication. Also, may you please put down the sources of this information, I would like to look into it more. If you need more details please ask. Thank You.

Comment: You'll need to find out what rules or procedures the airline(s) will impose, and follow them. In addition to whatever is required by the airline(s), she should carry a notarized letter from both parents (or two separate letters) stating that her parents give permission for her to travel on her own. In addition, of course, you'll have to make sure she's carrying the appropriate and valid travel documents (passport and visa).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which nationality she is and *I will assume she is a U.S. Citizen and her purpose of travel is "tourism"*, since that was not specified in your question.

First of all, U.S. travelers to Russia will need a valid passport and a Russian visa inside their passport. The major difference for getting the visa, for minors, is that they need to fill out some extra paperwork and additional documents.

According to the [travisa website](https://russia.travisa.com/VisaInstructions.aspx?CitizenshipID=US&CountryID=RU&TravelerTypeID=HSFM&ResidenceID=US&PartnerID=TA):

> a photocopy of the child's birth certificate and the parents' passport
>   information page and an original signed letter from at least one
>   parent must be included authorizing the Russian Consulate to issue the
>   Russian visa and explaining who the minor will be traveling with to
>   Russia.

My advice is that you call the Russian Visa processing company (ILS) in San Francisco. You will have to submit your visa documents and passport to them anyways, but please contact them to verify that your daughter can travel alone as a minor into Russia.

I tried calling the San Francisco office to clarify but it seems that their number does not work. So, I called the Washington DC office and they told me that it's perfectly fine for unaccompanied U.S. minors to fly to Russia, as long as the extra papers are filled out with the visa application. Please contact them at your earliest convenience.

San Francisco [Russian Visa Center (ILS) contact information](https://ils-usa.com/page/98?domain=5&language=10):

- Call-center: +1 202-827-0880
- Telephone: +1 415-860-0852
- E-mail: info-san-francisco@ils-usa.com
- Working hours: Monday-Friday: 9.00 a.m. - 4.00 p.m. (Passports pick up: 2.00 p.m. - 4.00 p.m.)
- Technical break: 1 p.m. - 2.00 p.m.

Washington D.C. [Russian Visa Center (ILS) contact information](https://ils-usa.com/page/96?domain=5&language=10):

- Call-center: +1 202-827-0880
- Telephone: +1 202-827-0895
- Fax: +1 202-827-0896
- E-mail: info-washington@ils-usa.com
- Working hours:
  Monday-Friday: 9.00 a.m. - 4.00 p.m. (Passports pick up: 2.00 p.m. - 4.00 p.m)
- Technical break: 1.00 p.m. - 2.00 p.m.